# How much Wait time is needed for new USA permanent residents to Apply for Student Financial Aid

Tags: united-states, fafsa, permanent-resident

How much Wait time is needed for new USA permanent residents to Apply for Student Financial Aid for Graduate and Undergraduate studies?

I heard you need to wait for one year until you can apply for Student Financial Aid (FAFSA) and they said that the same rule goes when you move from one state to another, you need to wait for at least one year !!!

Comment: There are many sources of student aid. Each has its own rules. Your school's student aid office can help you determine what you may be eligible for.

Comment: Non-citizens can at times qualify for federal student aid, so the idea that there is a one-year minimum wait doesn't sound right (the moving between states is certainly wrong): https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/eligibility/non-us-citizens But can't find a specific cite for new citizens at the moment. Note that if nothing else you are free to apply, answer all questions honestly, and if you don't qualify they will tell you.

Comment: Moving between states can affect whether a university or college will treat  you as a resident of the state. Residency can have a big effect on aid packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None. If you have been granted permanent residence you are eligible. See the [Federal Student Aid](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/eligibility/non-us-citizens#not-eligible-noncitizen) site, including the details under the [eligible non-citizen section](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/glossary#Eligible_Noncitizen) which details the visa types. This is echoed on the [FAFSA](https://fafsa.ed.gov/help.htm) site itself - if you have the 8 or 9 digit number to complete the form, you are eligible.

You must speak with your school's financial aid office to find out local details.

Comment: One last thing @gef05 Do they give financial Aid for graduate studies (Master's or phd's) or it is only for undergraduate studies ? and if they are giving for graduate studies, is it the same with undergraduate studies or it is reduced in percentage ?

Comment: I would say that it might be true for federal grants and aid, but for state specific grants and aid it may depend on length of time you've been living in that state. You'll have to prove the length with bills for example.